# About Mathematical Programs

Tags: optimization, benders-decomposition, decomposition

I am dealing with the following problem as follows.
$$\min \sum_{i,j}( x_{i}+y_{j}+q_{ij}+w_{i})$$

$$\text{s.t.} x_{i}+y_{j}+q_{ij}+w_{i} \geq b_{ij}, \forall i,j$$

Is it possible to handle this problem more efficiently??

**Edit:** All variables are continuous.

Comment: Which variables are integer and which are not, and which would you include in the master problem versus subproblem(s)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback! I updated the post according to the comment. In the second part of the comment, would you want me to add their master problems as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first subproblem is not separable, but your second subproblem is. You can split the second subproblem into one LP for each value of $i,$ since there are no variables with subscript $j$ that do not also have subscript $i.$

On the subject of stronger cuts, you may already be aware of it, but there is a stream of research, starting with a paper by Magnanti and Wong in 1981, on generating stronger Benders cuts. You might find a paper by Sherali and Lunday [1] interesting.

[1] Sherali, H.D., Lunday, B.J. On generating maximal nondominated Benders cuts. Ann Oper Res 210, 57–72 (2013). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10479-011-0883-6